# Moving image within frame ios

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

Ok, first off I'm sorry if this has been asked before. I couldn't find questions that exist my problem (but I'm sure they're here).

I want the user to be able to take a picture/choose a picture and then apply it in a frame but be able to move and scale it within the frame before choosing the final product.

I want to know how apps like PicFrame do this. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one image view for the picture and add another one on top for the frame. Then use gesture recognizers to change the position and scale of the picture view in response to user interaction.

Comment: so if I have an image in picture uiimageview, what do I assign to frame uiimageview?

Comment: Another image, showing a picture frame, I would guess. Make sure it's transparent in the middle.